# How to determine the PTGS for character with high power and low forte?

Tags: burning-wheel

Consider a character with power 4 and forte 2 (perhaps due to permanent injury reducing forte).

Mortal wound is 9, superficial is 2, and the interval between wound levels is 1. But this is not possible! For example, we might want to place light wound at 3, midi at 4, severe at 5 and traumatic at 6. The difference between 6 and 9 is three.

How does one calculate the PTGS in such a situation?

---

MW is 6 + average of power and forte, superficial is half of forte rounded down + 1.

Rules text under the heading Light, Midi, Severe and Traumatic

> Place the other wound tolerances in order left to right between superficial and mortal. They may be set apart by up to half the Forte exponent (rounded up). Typically, the only gaps are between superficial and light, and light and midi. Severe, traumatic and mortal all tend to fall together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maximum distance (half Forte rounded up) only dictates how far apart you can place Li, Mi, Se, and Tr, from left to right. It does not apply to the distance between Tr and MW, since MW is placed by its own rules and Tr is placed relative only to Se.

So yes, the tolerances with Forte 2 would be: **Su 2**, **Li 3**, **Mi 4**, **Se 5**, **Tr 6**, **MW 9**. This is legal, because the maximum distance of 1 while moving from left to right placing the middle tolerances has been respected. The space between Tr and MW is large, but this large top-end gap is the natural and by-design result of the placement rules, giving frail (low Forte) characters a natural vulnerability to harm.